# Jetpack Compose, vertical list with horizontal categories

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm starting my journey with the Jetpack Compose and I'm trying to port my screen from the XML approach to Compose but I have no idea how to implement it and if it is even possible.

Please take a look at the mockup below.

[image: Prewview of the screen]

The screen consists of a horizontal recycler view with the items representing categories (the currently visible category is marked with a solid background) and a vertical nested recycler view representing categories with the items.

- When the user is scrolling down, and the category title (e.g. "Category2") reaches half of the screen height (green line), then the category tile at the horizontal list is marked as selected and pulled is snipped to the left side of the recycler view.
- The user can scroll through the horizontal recycler view with categories, and when he clicks a category tile then the vertical list is automatically scrolled to that category

Could you please help me with the implementation of that Composable? My actual knowledge about nested lazy lists is insufficient to implement it, so I'd be very grateful if you could provide me the solution or at least point me to which mechanisms should I use, about which I should read.